# Any way to get multiple CFIFs displaying inside CFSET?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

At the moment I have this code which is working great -

```
<CFIF (DailyCount MOD 2) EQ 0>
<CFSET via = '<td style="background-color: DBEFB6;">#src#<br><font   color="blue">#get_info.csuseragent#</font></td>'>
<CFELSE>
<CFSET via = '<td>#src#<br><font color="blue">#get_info.csuseragent#</font></td>'>
</CFIF>
```

In the **#get_info.csuseragent#** field, at the moment it is displaying the whole UA string eg - *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20130406 Firefox/23.0*

I want to put the code below where the **#get_info.csuseragent#** tag is so it just displays the broswer/device. This works normally out of this setup but I cannot work out how to get it to display in that cell. Can anyone shed any light on how to get these CFIF statements to appear within this CFSET?

```
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "blackberry">Blackberry</CFIF> 
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "iphone">iPhone</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "ipad">iPad</CFIF> 
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "android">Android</CFIF>  
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "msie">IE</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "firefox">Firefox</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "chrome">Chrome</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "opera">Opera</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "Safari/534.53.10">Safari</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "Safari/534.57.2">Safari</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "Safari/533.21.1">Safari</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "Safari/533.19.4">Safari</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "Safari/533.18.5">Safari</CFIF>
<CFIF '#get_info.csuseragent#' contains "Safari/534.50">Safari</CFIF>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed tags within each other, so this is invalid syntax:

```
<cfset myVar = <cfif something>"fred"<cfelse>"barney"</cfif>>
```

What will work in your situation is to first set a variable:

```
<cfif get_info.csuseragent contains "blackberry">
    <cfset agent = "Blackberry">
<cfelseif get_info.csuseragent contains "iphone">
    <cfset agent = "iPhone">
etc
<cfelse>
    <cfset agent = "Unknown">
</cfif>
```

and then use it:

```
<cfset via = '<td style="background-color: DBEFB6;">#src#
<br><font color="blue">#agent#</font></td>'>
```

Comment: please don't use `'##'` when referencing a variable name. It's not necessary

Answer (score 3):

Once you upgrade to CF 9+ you can use ternary operators. I know you can't use this with CF8 so consider this a tip for the future.

ternary works best for simple if-else conditions and is very elegant in my opinion. The syntax is `condition ? true : false`

```
<cfset myVar = findNoCase('blackberry', agent) ? "Blackberry" : "unknown">
```

You can do nesting like this too but if it gets complicated to follow / maintain you're better off using `<cfscript>if(){}elseif(){}else{};</cfscript>` or `<cfif><cfelseif><cfelse></cfif>` for readability, not to mention I've never tested nested ternary efficiency. Personally I find this easy to read but to each his/her own...

```
<cfset myVar = findNoCase('blackberry', agent) ? "Blackberry" :
               findNoCase('iPhone', agent) ? "iPhone" :
               findNoCase('android', agent) ? "Android" :
               findNoCase('msie', agent) ? "Kill me now" :
               findNoCase('firefox', agent) ? "Firefox" :
               findNoCase('chrome', agent) ? "Chrome" :
               findNoCase('opera', agent) ? "Opera" :
               findNoCase('safari', agent)? "Safari" : "unknown">
```

Comment: I didn't even know that syntax was available.  I've only seen colons used with switch/case.

Comment: Not directly relevant here, but by way of a related tip: Railo 4.1 also has `x = y ?: z` syntax - as a shortcut for `x = isDefined('y') AND NOT isNull(y) ? y : z`

Comment: @DanBracuk several languages use this syntax including JavaScript.  It isn't new, just new to ColdFusion as of CF9. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score -1):

Use `cfsavecontent` instead of `cfset`.

please see the following docs showing how to do it.
http://cfquickdocs.com/?getDoc=cfsavecontent

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @P.J - Actually this is an "answer". Though it could be expanded to include some additional detail or an example ..